# FTP & PHP File Uploader, change directory

Tags: php, file, upload, ftp, directory

so i'm trying to make a ftp php uploader on my localhost setup with xampp.
It works fine to upload files from C:\xampp\htdocs\ but if I try to upload a file from my desktop it wont work. is there a way to get the path of the "source" file so I can upload from other places than ...\htdocs\ or how can I fix this?

Files are uploaded to a ftp folder on my desktop, and as I said that works fine when you chose a file from C:\xampp\htdocs.

```
<?php
if($_POST){
$source = basename($_FILES["source"]["name"]);
$fileType = pathinfo($source, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$remote_file = $source;
$ftp_server = '127.0.0.1';
$ftp_user_name = 'xxx';
$ftp_user_pass = 'xxx';

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);


$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);


if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $source, FTP_ASCII)) {
echo "successfully uploaded $source\n";
} else {
echo "There was a problem while uploading $source\n";
}


ftp_close($conn_id);
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" id="source" name="source"></input><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload file" name="submit"      id="submit"></input><br>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using the `name`. To access the file that was uploaded you need to use `tmp_name`. Change `$source = basename($_FILES["source"]["name"]);` to `$source = basename($_FILES["source"]["tmp_name"]);`

Comment: SOLUTION: I had tried that before but dident get it to work. Reason is I had the "$remote_file" = $source, that worked before when uploading stuff from \htdocs\ but I had to change that now. So you kinda solved it for me :) cheers